# What does "Out of memory error" refer to in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, out-of-memory

When a Google Apps Script function fails and returns "Out of memory error", what does that refer to?

Has the code reached a memory max for a particular variable? Does this have to do with the Cache Service? Does this have to do with the Script Database service? Does this have to do with the overall memory of script it self, combination of all the data processed and calculated?

I have found no information on this error and what it refers to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, 
James

Comment: This is related to Memory Quotas. It would be nice to know where you crossed the line, and indeed what the line is, but that's the subject of [Issue 1067: Show line number in "Out of memory" error](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1067)

Comment: I have crossed the line while retrieving data from Google Sites announcement page. I am retrieving over 1000 pages of data and on the 389 announcement page I receive the error. BUt the weird thing is, is that the script worked fine Monday and Tuesday of last week and only since Wednesday has the issue appeared.

Comment: I can only speculate that this is either a case of spotty enforcement (based on the comments in the issue link above), or the size of the pages you're retrieving has increased dramatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The same error I had faced was due to a variable increased in size more than permitted (Although I am not aware what the maximum permitted size is). So I believe its the "memory max for a particular variable reached" case. The workaround I used was to write the stream of data in a google doc instead. Its simple and works without any troubles.

The behavior of Google Apps Script is deceiving (at least for me) at times, ie. not observed consistency in its error messages. Probably one of those instances occurring with you.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code that produced the same error for me and the fixed code / solution as well! This may be of help for someone passing by.

```
function generateRandomNumbers(){
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    var temp = [];
    for(var j = 0; i < 81; j++){ // using i < 81 instead of j < 81 caused out of memory error!!!
      temp.push(Math.random());
    }
    result.push(temp);
  }
}
```

After changing `i < 18` to `j < 18`, that error went away. Here is the code that worked correctly without producing errors:

```
function generateRandomNumbers(){
  var result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
    var temp = [];
    for(var j = 0; j < 81; j++){
      temp.push(Math.random());
    }
    result.push(temp);
  }
}
```