# persistently sporadic out of memory error in Google Apps Scripts when copying data validations from a template

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have hundreds of Spreadsheets that were made from a template sheet. They all have the same number/name of sheets, rows, columns, etc...

I have added some data validations to the template. I want to copy the data validations from the template to each of the Spreadsheets. I have the code, and it works, but it throws a memory error.

It always throws the error -- the only thing that changes is how many destination Spreadsheets it has processed before it throws the error. Sometimes it'll process 4 Spreadsheets before it throws the error, sometimes 50, sometimes more/less. I cannot figure out why.

I trimmed my code down to a working sample. I can't share the source files but they are just normal Spreadsheets with 5 sheets/tabs and various data validations. If it matters, the data validations do use named ranges. For example: `=REGEXMATCH(LOWER(google_drive_url)   , "^https:\/\/drive\.google\.com\/drive\/folders\/[a-z0-9_-]{33}$")`.

I have commented the below code but here is a recap:

1. Get the template Spreadsheet and cache all of the data validations in it
2. Go through each destination Spreadsheet:

   1. Alear all of the data validations
   2. Apply the data validations from the template

In my real code I have an array of destination file IDs. For testing purposes I am just using one destination file and applying the data validations from the template multiple times.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sourceFileID = "1rB7Z0C615Kn9ncLykVhVAcjmwkYb5GpYWpzcJRjfcD8";
  var destinationFileID = "1SMrwTuknVa1Xky9NKgqwg16_JNSoHcFTZA6QxzDh7q4";

  // get the source file
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceFileID);
  var sourceDataValidationCache = {};

  // go through each sheet and get a copy of the data validations
  // cache them for quick access later
  sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function(sourceSheet){
    var sheetName = sourceSheet.getName();

    // save all the data validations for this sheet
    var thisSheetDataValidationCache = [];

    // get the full sheet range
    // start at first row, first column, and end at max rows and max columns
    // get all the data validations in it
    // go through each data validation row
    sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getMaxRows(), sourceSheet.getMaxColumns()).getDataValidations().forEach(function(row, rowIndex){
      // go through each column
      row.forEach(function(cell, columnIndex){
        // we only need to save if there is a data validation
        if(cell)
        {
          // save it
          thisSheetDataValidationCache.push({
            "row" : rowIndex + 1,
            "column" : columnIndex + 1,
            "dataValidation" : cell
          });
        }
      });
    });

    // save to cache for this sheet
    sourceDataValidationCache[sheetName] = thisSheetDataValidationCache;
  });

  // this is just an example
  // so just update the data validations in the same destination numerous times to show the memory leak
  for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    // so we can see from the log how many were processed before it threw a memory error
    Logger.log(i);

    // get the destination
    var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationFileID);

    // go through each sheet
    destinationSpreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function(destinationSheet){
      var sheetName = destinationSheet.getName();

      // get the full range and clear existing data validations
      destinationSheet.getRange(1, 1, destinationSheet.getMaxRows(), destinationSheet.getMaxColumns()).clearDataValidations();

      // go through the cached data validations for this sheet
      sourceDataValidationCache[sheetName].forEach(function(dataValidationDetails){
        // get the cell/column this data validation is for
        // copy it, build it, and set it
        destinationSheet.getRange(dataValidationDetails.row, dataValidationDetails.column).setDataValidation(dataValidationDetails.dataValidation.copy().build());
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Is there something wrong with the code? Why would it throw an out of memory error? Is there anyway to catch/prevent it?

Comment: What's the error message you're receiving?

Comment: “Out of memory”. With no other details or information. And I can’t catch it with a `try...catch`.

Comment: As of now there is not a way to catch where the error occurs, there is an [open issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/36754297) at Google's Issue Tracker, so you can take a look at that. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453621/11581830), the issue probably lies in a particular variable that is exceeding the limit, this could be happening to `thisSheetDataValidationCache` in your case, since you push so much information to it.

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't fail when writing to that variable. It will do at minimum 1 iteration meaning it successfully wrote to that variable and then even read from it. The out of memory error happens after the iterations start and nothing is getting written to any variable there...

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a better idea of what's failing I suggest you keep a counter of the iterations, to know how many are going through.

I also just noticed the line

`sourceSheet.getRange(1, 1, sourceSheet.getMaxRows(), sourceSheet.getMaxColumns()).getDataValidations().forEach(function(row, rowIndex){`

This is not a good idea, because `getMaxRows()` & `getMaxColumns()` will get the total number of rows in the sheet, not the ones with data, meaning, if your sheet is 100x100 and you only have data in the first 20x20 cells, you'll get a range that covers the entire 10,000 cells, and then calling a `forEach` means you go through every cell.

A better approach to this would be using `getDataRange()`, it will return a range that covers the entirety of your data ([Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)). With that you can use a much smaller range and considerably less cells to process.

Comment: The `for` loop is the iteration. That is how I know that some are getting processed. Sometimes it'll process 4 Spreadsheets before it throws the error, sometimes 50, sometimes more/less. Each sheet has a different number of rows but at most 30 rows and 30 columns. I tried with `getDataRange` but it yields the same problem.

Comment: The problem I see if that when you push to `thisSheetDataValidationCache` you're doing it for the validation of every cell. Then inside the loop, you're removing, evaluating, copying and then re-building the validation rules on every cell of every sheet in the Spreadsheet, I don't know if it could be an issue on how `forEach` manages data. Your code looks fine to me (the comments help a lot), I just think doing all of the processing cell by cell, for several different things is where your issue is, regardless of how many rows/cols it has (checking every sheet in several Spreadsheets, right?)

Comment: But it’s not doing it for every cell. It only caches valuations for cells that have it. `if(cell)`

Comment: After checking further, in the [issue report](https://issuetracker.google.com/36754297) I mentioned above, it is mentioned that the memory quotas had been disabled temporarily due to a bug but that they were operational once again. I think we'll have to wait until they display line # for that error (part of the request in the report) to better debug what is happening with your code.