# Google Apps Scripts - Out of Memory Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am writing about a problem my org is having, as a result I have to be a bit vague (though I have permission to post this).

I am writing a script parse a google-sheet that has a column with numerical data in it.  I need the script to return a set of ranges (strings in A1 notation for use elsewhere).  The ranges have to correspond to real ranges in the script for which the numerical data sums to *as close to* 0.25 as possible but not more than .25, and return all ranges in the sheet for which this is true.  E.g. if my sheet data was

A (COLUMN HEADER)
DataHeader (A1)
.1 (A2)
.01 (A3)
.04 (A4)
.1 (A5)
.03 (A6)
.02 (A7)
.1 (A8)
.05 (A9)
.04 (A10)
.07 (A11)

my script should return the array [A2:A4,A5:A10,A11], because A2:A4 sum to exactly .25, while A5:A10 sum to below (but close to) .25 but including A11 would get us above .25. A11 is included because I still need the data there.

In reality, my script will return larger ranges in A1 notation, but the problem I'm having is occuring in my attempt to properly construct a running sum and return the rows of interest.

My script is broken into 2 functions at the moment, because I was tackling the problems I was having in pieces.

The first script IDs the following info: The data to examine, as well as the number of rows from the top of the sheet that the start of the data
`var data`
and
`var A1offset`
respectively

The second function does a running sum of an array of my data and build an array of row number pairs representing the ranges at which the sum is just below .25.  I have pasted the portion throwing an error below.

```js
  var result = [] //empty array to store row number pairs.
  //data is a previously obtained array of my data of interest
  //A1offset is the number of rows between the top of the sheet and the start of data
  for (var i = 0;i<data.length;i++){
      cursum += data[i][0]//add current value to cursum
    if( cursum >= .25 && result.length<1){//if we are @ the beginning add first rownum (A1 Notation) of data to result
      i=i-1 //Go back one so that i++ runs, we don't miss this datapoint.
      cursum = 0 //reset  
      result.push([(A1offset),(i + A1offset )])// 
    }
    else if( cursum >= .25 && result.length>=1){
      i=i-1//go back one
      cursum = 0//reset
      result.push([(result[result.length-1][1]+1),(i+A1offset)]) //Add to result a pair of values, the 
      //row after the end of the last range and the current row.


    }
  }
```

The issue:

Previously, I did not have the 
`i = i-1`
statement but I realized I needed that or
`i--`
However after adding these two statements, upon running my code I get an 'Out of Memory error' error.

*However*, this does not happen if I loop over a smaller dataset.  Experimentally, I have found that if I use

`for (var i=0;i<.85*data.length;i++){`
it runs fine.

data has 4978 elements in it.

Question: Is there an upper limit to the number of iterations a google script can run? I was under the impression that if there was, it was *much* higher than 4978 (or closer to 5050, since I'm using the i=i-1 statement)

Or, did I simply write poor code? Or both?

Thank you for any insights you can provide, I don't have a CS degree so frequently I run into issues where I don't know what I don't know.

Please let me know if I have not provided enough information.'

Edited to add a link to a test version of my [sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fHd9NExEyOQJj1E8wZavupVCC3UEi3sN9X8lm3JNCa0/edit?folder=0AOGDV7ZdjVB4Uk9PVA&pli=1#gid=0) as well as the entire script below (overcommented to be certain):

```js
function IDDATA() {
  //ID the data to sum
  var spsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //Get spreadsheet
  var tab = spsheet.getSheetByName("Test") //Get data sheet
  var Drows = tab.getRange("A:A").getValues() //All values in Column D


  var filledvals =  Drows.filter(String).length //Length of filled in rows in Column D
   //Subtract out the header row from the length of values
 // Logger.log(datarows)
  var offset = 0 //Initialize at 0.  Offset is the distance (ZERO INDEXED <-THIS IS IMPORTANT!) between row 1 and the data 
  var ct1 = 0//initialize counter 1 at 0
  while(Drows[ct1][0].indexOf("DATA")<0){ //Look at the ct1 Row of the 0th column of Column D

    ct1++//Count until a the row with DATA in it. indexOf(String) returns -1 if the string is not found.
  }

  offset = ct1 //set offset to ct1.  
  var A1offset = ct1 + 2//Assume that all data has a header row, and create an offset variable that points to the first row of NUMERICAL  data.  
  var datarows = filledvals-2 //Gets us the ROW NUMBER of the last filled in row in D:D, which should be the LAST number in the data.

  return([datarows,offset,A1offset])


}

function RUNSUM(){
  var firstcol = "A"
  var lastcol = "A"
  var spsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); //Get spreadsheet
  var tab = spsheet.getSheetByName("Test") //Get sheet
  var vararray = IDDATA()
  var len = vararray[0] //Length of data
  var offset = vararray[1] //Unused?
  var A1offset = vararray[2]//The offset from 0, but to be used in A1 Notation
//  Logger.log(typeof(A1offset))
  var startrow = "A"+A1offset//The first row to get data from in the column that has system size data.
  var endrow = "A"+(len+A1offset)//The last row to get data from that has system size data.
  var cursum = 0 //Initialize @ 0, the current sum of system size data.
  var range = tab.getRange(startrow+":"+endrow) //Range to examine, in A1 notation Could probably use other forms of getRange()....
  var data = range.getValues() //Values in range to exampine

  var testmax = Math.floor(.85*data.length)

  var result = [] //Positions, initialize as empty array

  //var exceptions = [] //Rows that contain non-numbers

  for (var i = 0;i<.8*data.length;i++){//.8* because of memory error
   /* if(isNaN(data[i][0])){ //if data[i][0] is Not a Number
       exceptions.push((i+A1offset).toFixed(0))//push the row number to exclude from eventual csv
       continue //skip to next i 
     }*/

      cursum += data[i][0]//add current value to cursum
    if( cursum > .25 && result.length<1){//if we are @ the beginning, we need to know, see results.push statement below

      i=i-1

      cursum = 0 //reset


      result.push([(A1offset),(i + A1offset )])// 

    }
    else if( cursum > .25 && result.length>=1){

      i=i-1//go back one     
      cursum = 0//reset

      result.push([(result[result.length-1][1]+1),(i+A1offset)])
    }
  }

  var rangearray = []
  var intarray = [] //declare an empty array to intermediate array vals todo: remove in favor of single loop

  for(var k = 0; k < result.length; k++){
    intarray.push([result[k][0].toFixed(0),result[k][1].toFixed(0)])//build array of arrays of result STRING vals w/out decimal pts. 
  }

  for (var j = 0;j<result.length;j++){
    rangearray.push(firstcol+intarray[j][0]+":"+lastcol+intarray[j][1])

  }
  Logger.log(rangearray)
  return rangearray
}
```

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402719/what-does-out-of-memory-error-refer-to-in-google-apps-script

Comment: Could you post the script please? Not just a single portion of it.

Comment: Hello @dinofan, in order to properly troubleshoot this issue we will need an example sheet with the data (minimal data - the numbers themselves should be enough) and all the code you are using to operate on it. Furthermore, I'd like to ask, if you had the following data in the first column: `0.3, 0.2, 1, 1, 0.3` should the result be [A1:A4, A2:A5] (overlapping ranges)? As far as I am concerned your current algorithm will not find those cases.

Comment: @carlesgg97, working on getting the data to you! Thanks your help.  Regarding your question about the data `0.3,0.2,1,1,.3`: What I'm after is separating out a set of ranges where the data in the column I'm investigating sums to .25 (or just below) *not* finding all ranges where that's true.  So, when I find the first range where the sum is .25, that range is "frozen", so to speak and I move on to the next row to start looking again.  Eventually the information in the cells surrounding the sumrange will be exported to CSVs.

Comment: @carlesgg97, I've added a link to some test data as well as my whole script per Diego's request.  Please let me know if you can't access the sheet!

Comment: Hey @dinofan thanks for the info provided! I have managed to find the error (see below answer). If you need anything else don't hesitate to add a comment/create a new question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Sheet you provided, the cell `4548` contains the number `0.2584`.

Your algorithm, upon finding that number, will insert it into the `result` array and decrement i, creating an infinite loop that appends data into your array.

In order to fix your issue, in the `RUNSUM()` function right after the for loop declaration (`for (var i = 0;i<data.length;i++)`), you should handle this situation (or otherwise, make your data "valid" by removing that outlier value).

Furthermore, I have rewritten the algorithm in the hopes of making it more clear and stable (see that it now handles the last range, and ignores values over 0.25). I believe this may be interesting to you:

```js
function myAlgorithm() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Test');
  var values = sheet.getRange("A6:A").getValues();
  var l = 0;
  var results = []; // 1-indexed results
  var currentSum = 0;
  var offset = 5;

  for (var i=0; i<values.length && typeof values[i][0] == 'number'; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] >= 0.25) {
      // Ignore the value larger or equal than 0.25
      Logger.log('Found value larger or equal than 0.25 at row %s', i+1+offset);
      if (l<i) {
        results.push([l+1+offset, i+offset, currentSum]);
      }
      l = i+1;
      currentSum = 0;
    } else {
      if (currentSum + values[i][0] > 0.25) {
        results.push([l+1+offset, i+offset, currentSum]);
        l = i;
        currentSum = values[i][0];
      } else {
        currentSum += values[i][0];
      }
    }
  }

  // handle last range after exitig the for-loop
  if (l<i) {
    results.push([l+1+offset, i+offset, currentSum]);
  }
  for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(results[i]);
  }
}
```

Finally, if you decide to modify your code in order to handle this situation, I suggest you check out the information in the following link:

- [Troubleshooting in GAS](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/troubleshooting#debugging)

Comment: I need to go through your answer to make sure I understand it, but I fully expect to choose this as my accepted answer.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I can't believe I wasn't using the debugger.  My professors would be very disappointed.  I think that the only part I am not grasping is what `var l` is doing here.

Comment: @dinofan haha. The debugger definitely is very useful in GAS! Regarding the `l` variable (could have also called it `left`, `start`, etc.) it points the 0-base index of the first element in the current range. You can see that when pushing a result, I one to `l` (to make it 1-based) and also add the "offset" (in this case 5, due to starting at cell `A6`). Hope that makes sense. Cheers!

Comment: I think it does! It's very clever, consider my socks blown off.