# How to combine these arrays on criteria basis using GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script

This one may seem silly, bbut got caught up with an `Out of memory` error while it seems right to me.

```
let array1 = 
[
 [1,"2022-04-12T03:00:00.000Z","Maria","SE",3,11601,"Blusa",5,3,true],
 [1,"2022-04-12T03:00:00.000Z","Maria","SE",5,11601,"Blusa",10,10,true]
]
```

```
let array2 = 
[
 [2,11601,"Blusa 34","","","","","",2],
 [3,11601,"Blusa 34","","","","","",1]
]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
let result= 
[
 [2,11601,"Blusa 34","","","","","",2],
 [3,11601,"Blusa 34","","","","","",4],
 [5,11601,"Blusa 34","","","","","",10],
]
```

...where the 8th element of `array1` gets summed up with `array2`'s 8th element - if the item exists in `array2`, it doesn't get pushed into it, but rather the qtd is updated only.

Here's my shot at it:

```
for (let n = 0; n < array1.length; n++) {
    for (let a = 0; a < array2.length; a++) {
      if (array1[a][4] === array2[n][0]) {
        let qty= Number(array2[a][8]) + Number(array1[n][8]);
        array1[n][8] = qty;
      } else {
        array2.push([array1[a][4], array1[a][5], array1[a][6], '', '', '', '', array1[a][8], ''])
      }
    }
  }
```

Thank you!

Comment: About the error of `Out of memory`, can I ask you about the length of `array1` and `array2`?

Comment: Hi, @Tanaike. I've logged them and their lengths are no more than 5 Thank you!

Comment: We can't reproduce the `Out of memory error` using the script you've provided above. We can only [speculate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14453621) what could be causing this error. Perhaps you could double check your script & give additional details to help us reproduce the error, that way it would help us dissect your issue further.

Comment: Thank you for replying. And, I apologize for my late reply. Now, I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer.

Comment: Thank you, @Tanaike! The answer below reproduces the wrong result, but I have been able to resolve it by structuring the script differently. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: I'll do it, @Tanaike! Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several problems I find with your script.  Although I don't get an `Out of memory` error I do get `Cannot read property '4' of undefined` because you have inadvertently switched indeces `a`and `n`.  And array2 keeps expanding with `push` so not sure if that is what you intended.

**Code.gs**

```
function test() {
  try {
    let array1 = [
                  [1,"2022-04-12T03:00:00.000Z","Maria","SE",3,11601,"Blusa",5,3,true],
                  [1,"2022-04-12T03:00:00.000Z","Maria","SE",5,11601,"Blusa",10,10,true]
                 ];
    let array2 = [
                  [2,11601,"Blusa 34","","","","","",2],
                  [3,11601,"Blusa 34","","","","","",1]
                 ];
    for (let n = 0; n < array1.length; n++) {
      for (let a = 0; a < array2.length; a++) {
        if (array1[n][4] === array2[a][0]) {
          let qty= Number(array2[a][8]) + Number(array1[n][8]);
          array1[n][8] = qty;
        } else {
          array2.push([array1[n][4], array1[n][5], array1[n][6], '', '', '', '', array1[n][8], ''])
        }
      }
    }
    console.log(array1);
    console.log(array2);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
7:26:58 AM  Info    [ [ 2, 11601, 'Blusa 34', '', '', '', '', '', 2 ],
  [ 3, 11601, 'Blusa 34', '', '', '', '', '', 1 ],
  [ 3, 11601, 'Blusa', '', '', '', '', 3, '' ],
  [ 5, 11601, 'Blusa', '', '', '', '', 10, '' ],
  [ 5, 11601, 'Blusa', '', '', '', '', 10, '' ],
  [ 5, 11601, 'Blusa', '', '', '', '', 10, '' ] ]
```

Comment: I'm assuming that creating a new array to get the resulting rows would be the right approach to elliminte this increasing length related issue? Thank you